# Reactjs app fetch an api has been block by CORS even on server not localhost

Tags: reactjs, node.js, cors, fetch

I'm using reactjs app and I upload it on my website's cpanel. after using npm run build , I'm getting same error on localhost:3000 and my website domain. I'm trying fetch an api from cross origin website.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account?recvWindow=20000&timestamp=1603858555542&signature=f2d***' from origin 'https://app.mydomain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-mbx-apikey is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I tried to use Express along with reactjs but it didn't work, too. for localhost I can use electronjs to solve the problem. but for my app which has been uploaded on my site what should I do?
This is a test that I did with xmlhttprequest:

```
console.log('test:');
var burl = 'https://api.binance.com';
var dataQueryString = 'recvWindow=20000&timestamp=' + Date.now();
var keys = {
  'akey':'/****/',
  'skey':'/****/',
};
var endPoint = '/api/v3/account';
var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(dataQueryString, keys['skey']).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);;
var url = burl + endPoint + '?' + dataQueryString + '&signature=' + signature;
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET',url,true);
ourRequest.setRequestHeader('X-MBX-APIKEY',keys['akey']);
ourRequest.onload = function(){
  var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
  console.log('ourData:',ourData);
}
ourRequest.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

in your React app first install `http-proxy-middleware` and then in the root directory create a file named `setupProxy.js` and past this code:

```js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    "/**",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "https://api.binance.com",
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, but it doesn't work, unfortunately. the same error appeared. Any other suggestion? Or may I did it wrong somewhere?

Comment: check React documentation [link] (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)

Comment: I create react app newly and it hasn't serviceWorker.js and instead react creates something differenet named reportsWebVitals.js . It can be important for happening that?

Comment: It worked fine on localhost now, but when I uploaded build folder on cpanel it doesn't work again.